# extra character after writeUTF

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app. It send data to Java-based programm. Android code:

```
      Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.0.3.2"), 5555);

        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);


        out.writeUTF(jsonLoginData.toString()); 

//       IN jsonLoginData i put some values in another part of code
//        jsonLoginData = new JSONObject();
//        jsonLoginData.put("login",login);
//        jsonLoginData.put("password",password);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

So in another side i have Java based proram which is listenning 5555 port and getting data:

```
// var "s" is a socked listening 5555 port 

InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

  String line;
  String r = "";
  StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(); 

      // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
           {
             r = r + line;
           }

   bufferedReader.close();

    System.out.println("\n ==>" + r);
```

But the problem is that every time i have extra character in var "r".
Console shows me:

```
==> <{"password":"6f3fa6ad89a459af8e1819c514059b3","login":"456"} 

==> ={"password":"e516fac382793b462d6a19fa849db53a","login":"456"} 

==> B{"password":"6f3fa6ad89a459af8e1819c514059b3","login":"456111414"}
```

As you can see there is strange symboles before "{...}"like "<" or "=" or "B".
Don`t understand why id going so...

Comment: Have you logged `jsonLoginData.toString()` to make sure that it doesn't contain the strange symbols?

Comment: If you are writing to a `DataOutputStream`, then you should read from a `DataInputStream`.  If you want to read from an `InputStream` then write to an `OutputStream`.  Do not mix stream types, otherwise you may well get unintended effects, as you have found.

Comment: @rossum - they are not, on their own, deciding to throw in a DataOutputStream. There must be a magical tutorial that everybody seems to be copying from, and I'm dying to know which.

Comment: @bayou.io I doubt it. It's a common enough error. More likely people just don't actually read the Javadoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `DataOutputStream`. Just write your bytes to the `OutputStream`.

```
OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = jsonLoginData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
sout.write(bytes);
```

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to use the DataFooStream versions? Is DataInputStream still preferable in any sense?

Comment: But this does not meet if the requirements need String not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

From the Document webpage:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream#writeUTF(java.lang.String)

> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
> writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is
> the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
> string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
> in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character.

Therefore, the extra characters are intentionally added by the writeUTF method. I have no idea why they added this. Does not look useful to me. Probably caused more confusion than anything.